IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible + Excel file broken
I am new in Python and do not find the solution to solve this issue. When I launch this script I have this error message : IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible.
Moreover, this script corrupt the excel file. The file is broken after this.
import pandas as pd
import numpy
  
# opening the source excel file 
filename = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\Excel To Automatize\file.xlsx"
wb1 = pd.read_excel(filename)

sheets = ["Efdfg", "khefjkh", "jdshfjhd"] 

df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheets))

with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = "a" ) as writer:
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Aggregate Table", Index = False)



you didn't specify what line generates the error. my best guess is df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = sheets)) If so, check if any of the sheet names specified on the sheets list exist in the given file (it seems that the excel reader can't find any of the names in the file to concat).

Thank you very much for your answer Ze'ev. Find Below a part of the error message. TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Index'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/d95707/Projects/Test.py", line 14, in 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Aggregate Table", Index = False)

Im not sure its a problem of sheets list because when I try with a print(df), the df is correct and its what I need to be paste in the sheet "Aggregate Table" :)

Is it possible that the "Aggregate Table" sheet already exists? if so, you have to add ExcelWriter the if_sheet_exists parameter with the value "replace" or "overlay"

Indeed the "Aggregate Table" already exists and is empty. I tried to relaunch the script deleting the sheet "Aggregate Table" but I cannot check if it works because the excel file is corrupted :( . Thank you for your help.

Update: TypeError: ( to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Index' ) removing Index = False , permit me to open the file !!!!! But now the other issue is that Python overwrited all the preivous sheets in the file. I want to keep all existing sheets and add one "Aggregate Table "

I believe that you should read each sheet to a different dataframe (or a list of dataframes if more convenient) and inside with-writer you should save each dataframe to its sheet.

Because when I use pd.read_excel(filename), it does not read all sheets in filename ?

it reads all sheets and you concatenate them into one df, so you can't save them separately each one back to its sheet. you can first read_excel with sheet_name=sheets into df_dict it creates a dictionary of df and then you can contact into one df. And with writer you can write (using loop} df_dict[sheet].to_excel

Oh I understand, in another way when I create the df (concatenate) , I overwrite them more or less.

I found a plan B, Thank you for your help Ze'ev
